# Need explanation on event change handler code

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react and struggling to understand this piece of code

```
     const handleChange = (filterAttribute: SearchableAttribute) => (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
    val: string[]
  ) => {
    const currentCriteria = {
      attribute: filterAttribute,
      values: val
    };

    if (currentCriteria?.values !== null) {
      AddOrReplaceCriteria(currentFilter.criteria, currentCriteria);
    }
  };
```

The part (filterAttribute: SearchableAttribute) , if that is the parameter to be passed to the handler, what is the part 
(
    e: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
    val: string[]
  ) ?
I guess the last part with {} is the  body of the function to handle the event, but I am struggling to understand the two Parameters section before the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleChange` - function that returns a function

Simpler example:

```
const sum = (a: number) => (b: number) => {
    return a + b;
}

const f1 = sum(1); // (b: number) => number
const result = f1(2); // 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's throw away the TypeScript additions and just look at JavaScript to simplify this:

```
const handleChange = (filterAttribute) => (e, val) => { 
    // Function body
}
```

`handleChange` is a function which accepts *one* argument (`filterAttribute`) and has a return value of **another function**.

The function it returns accepts two arguments, `e` and `val`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're aware of the concept of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It's a function pointing to another function.

```
const func1 = ()=> {
const greeting='hey';
const func2 = () => alert(greeting);
return func2;
}

let invoke = func1();
invoke(); // Alerts hey
```